# How to match !x but not !!x in JS regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following text:

`This is!!xa simple string!xpattern`

I would like to get a regexp that matches the `!x` that's between "string" and "pattern" but not `!!xa` that's between "is" and "a".

This regexp is to be used inside a string `split()`.

I have tried several combinations but I cannot get a regexp that meets my needs. Perhaps my expression is not so regular after all =)

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:**

**SOLUTION**

Just to state clear the solution is going to be:

`s.replace(/(([^!])|^)!x/g,'$1SOME_MAGICAL_STRING').split(/SOME_MAGICAL_STRING/)`

Thanks for the solution idea to both **jvenema** and **Amarghosh**. And also to everyone that provided feedback too.

Comment: Solutions matching `[^!]` before the string aren't ideal, because they really have to be `(^|[^!])`... and then you should make them noncapturing... and it won't work if it's a multiple-character excluded prefix... you get the idea. Negative lookaround as in Daniel Brückner's answer is much prettier.

Comment: Do you really mean between `is` and `a`? Or do you mean between `is!` and `a`?

Comment: @Peter Bailey What I stated is that I do not want it to match the `!!x` that's between `is` and `a`.

@Jefromi Yes, Daniel Brückner's answer is indeed the best however JS doesn't  support it.

Comment: May be you can replace all `!!x` with `SOME_STRING_NOT_IN_CURRENT_STRING` and replace them back later.

Comment: @mpeterson so it's okay to split on the `!x` found in `!!x` when `!!x` *is not* surrounded by `is` and `a`?

Comment: @Peter Bailey no, what I meant is that it should avoid `!!x` at all cases (Use `!!` to escape the `!`)

Comment: So the `is` and `a` are completely irrelevant.  Just arbitrary in this example.  Got it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var s = "This is!!xa simple string!xpattern";
s.replace(/[^!]!x/,'-');
```

output:

```
"This is!!xa simple strin-pattern"
```

**Edit:** I missed the g, my bad. This one works:

```
var s = "!xThis is!!xa simple string!xpattern";
s.replace(/(([^!])|^)!x/g,'$1-');
```

output:

```
"-This is!!xa simple string-pattern"
```

All we're doing is matching the preceding character and then including it back into the replacement.

Comment: Won't this replace `g!x` with `-`?

Comment: Pretty sure he wants to not match the "g".

Comment: Has the same problem than the solution from BalusC.

Comment: yes, that works for a replace because I can use backreferences but not for a split(). Saying that I could do what Amarghosh suggested and replace it with a magical string and then split it.

Comment: Just to state clear the solution is going to be:

`s.replace(/(([^!])|^)!x/g,'$1SOME_MAGICAL_STRING').split(/SOME_MAGICAL_STRING/)`

Thanks for the solution to both jvenema and Amarghosh

Answer (score -1):

This expression should do the job. It uses a negative look behind assertion to assert that there is only a single exclamation mark.

```
(?<!!)!x
```

Comment: I've never seen that expression before, what does `(?<expr)` mean? I've tried your regexp in regexpal.com but doesn't work, perhaps that web it's not properly coded. I'll try it on my code.

Comment: Javascript doesn't support negative look-behinds (or look-behinds at all)

Comment: It's a lookbehind expression, like `(?!` is lookahead. However you don't get lookbehind in JavaScript's RegExp, and even lookahead has serious problems in IE.

Comment: @mpeterson it's `(?<!REGEX)` syntax for negative look-behind http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html unfortunately javascript doesn't support look-behind

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for that. Too bad it isn't supported by javascript though.

Comment: (?<EXPR) just checks if text to the left of the current position matches EXPR - if not, it fails. (?=EXPR) looks to the right of the current position and adding an exclamation mark inverts the result of the test in both cases. An assertion never consumes any characters.

Comment: Something learned - did not know that JavaScript does not support it.

Answer (score -1):

Too bad JS doesn't have lookbehind :) Assuming no `!x!x`, You can use `RegExp.exec` instead of `String.split`, as in

```
rx = /((?:[^!]|![^x])+)(?:!x|$)/g
res = []
while ((m = rx.exec("This is!!xa simple string!xpattern")))
  res.push(m[1]);
```

Here, `(?:[^!]|![^x])+` matches one or more non-exclamation point, or a `!` *not* followed by an `x`. This latter case gets rid of the `!!`. The `(?:!x|$)` consumes the `!x` terminator.

---

Edit: Since `!x!x` can happen, the loop has to be modified a bit to avoid infinite loop.

```
rx = /((?:[^!]|![^x])*)(?:!x|$)/g
res = []
str = "This is!!xa simpl!!xe!x!x string!xpattern"
while (true) {
  var m = rx.exec(str);
  if (m.index >= str.length)
    break;
  res.push(m[1]);
}
res
```

Comment: I could have two consecutive `!x` in my pattern.

Comment: The solution found proves to be much simpler but great idea though.